# What do I need to add to my dailymotion embed code to make video play on iOS?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, embed, dailymotion-api

The video plays fine on my computer, but I want to make it play on devices like iPhones and such. I'm an absolute beginner at all this and appreciate all the help I can get. Here's the code as it exists on my site, please just tell me what to add or change. Thank you!

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3om8ig?api=postMessage&amp;id=player&amp;syndication=lr:167083&amp;autoplay=1&amp;mute=0&amp;info=0&amp;logo=0&amp;related=0&amp;social=0&amp;controls=0&amp;start=0&amp;html=1&amp;chromeless=1&amp;highlight=FFCC33"></iframe>
```

Comment: in order for the community to help you, you need to describe what you've done exactly (so you have a page with this code, right? do you have a link?) and what the issue is on your iphone: does the video load ? play ? do you have a black player ? an error message ? any log, console message or othe detail is welcomed

Comment: Apologies, I uploaded a video to Dailymotion, then embedded the code on my site. It plays fine if you go to pantheonentertainment.com, but when I try to open it on my iPhone it doesn't show up. There's no error message, it's just black. I'm hoping there's just another bit of code I can add to make it play, but I don't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different player parameters in the url of the video in your iframe, do you truly need all of them? You will find the documentation at https://developer.dailymotion.com/player. We'll do a quick review here:

- api=postMessage : enables the Player API => only needed if you use the player API, so you can probably remove it
- id=player: ID of the player unique to the page to be passed back with all API messages. => only needed if you use the player API, so you can probably remove it
- syndication=lr:167083 : this is used if you have a syndication key, in case you are a partner and you want to track your generated revenues. If this is not your own syndication key, I suggest you remove this parameter!
- autoplay=1 : will autoplay the video. This parameter may not work on some mobile OS versions as most mobile devices prevent the video from auto playing to save user's bandwidth.
- controls=0 : the video controls will not be displayed
- html=1 : this is a testing parameter that should not be used for production purposes
- chromeless=1 : we recommend you to remove this parameter as it removes all the player UI, so you user won't be able to interact with the video (play it, pause it, etc)

Hence we suggest you remove all the cited parameters that will not be useful for you, and use the following iframe instead:

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3om8ig?mute=0&info=0&logo=0&related=0&social=0&highlight=FFCC33"></iframe>
```

Then, you video will play fine on mobile. What happened is that with the combination of chromeless=0 , autoplay=0 and controls=0 , your videos could not start automatically on mobile and you had hidden the controls for the user to start it. Hence you only had a black rectangle instead of the player.

With the code I mentioned, the video will play muted, without the dailymotion logo, without the sharing on social networks button, etc. You can changed all this by removing the remaining player parameters.